# Any other ways to execute Integration rather than viewing it as the inverse of Differentiation?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm learning the basics of Calculus. I'm good at differentiating (basic level). But when it comes to integration, it seems tricky as it takes time for me to think of a function for which the given one is the derivative. People seem to use some tricks when integrating two or more functions in multiplication by assigning one as u and representing the other as a derivative of u and so on.

My question is - Is there any other intuitively pleasing way to integrate rather than this differentiation-dependent approach, which is difficult to convince my mind as it is not that intuitive?

Comment: Does your calculus text have a chapter on "techniques of integration"?

Comment: Yes there are infinitely many ways , Euclidean space is only one of many spaces that they are inverse of each other , first intuitive way is just thinking of it as Riemann sums , takes a bit of practice but then it becomes second nature. There is also the complex integration methods where one can compute the real integral as a process. At any rate do not see them as inverse or not inverse but as what frame would be of help

Comment: 1. At this point of calculus, I'd tell students Ashleigh Brilliant's aphorism: _To be sure of hitting the target, shoot first and call what you hit `the target'._ Then we'd "shoot" -- compute a bunch of derivatives, and build up a library of functions we knew how to antidifferentiate. 2. There are formulas for differentiating products, quotients, and compositions of functions with known derivatives. _There do not exist_ analogous formulas for general antiderivatives, only for special cases. The point is, your cognitive asymmetry is warranted!

Comment: integration is hard: https://xkcd.com/2117/

Comment: For definite integrals, if all you want is a number that represents the value of the definite integral between two specific bounds (for example, $0$ and $\pi$), there are *numeric integration* techniques that don't involve looking for functions with useful derivatives.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: +1 for mentioning Ashleigh B.

Answer (score 3):

Integration is much more than a clever search for expressions that have the right derivative. The fundamental theorem of calculus is, in a way, the answer to your question.

If you can find an antiderivative of some function (using some technique you've learned or a clever trick you stumble on*) then it's easy to find the area under that function over some interval: it's the difference between the values of the antiderivative.

If you can't find a nice expression for an antiderivative using tools you know (and sometimes that will be provably impossible) you can always find a not so nice one by laboriously calculating areas under its graph using Riemann sums or any other argument using limits that gives you numerical estimates as good as you wish.

(*) If it is really the clever tricks you want to know more about, you can search for integration tricks. [Here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integration-tricks/) is one such link.